# THREE.SpriteCanvasMaterial is not a constructor | Angular 7

Tags: javascript, angular, three.js

I am using Angular 7 project and I want to add THREE JS to my project with this [document code](https://threejs.live/#/canvas_particles_waves) from the official website of THREE after that when I start to run project it shows me an error like:

```
core.js:15723 ERROR TypeError: THREE.SpriteCanvasMaterial is not a constructor
at init (<anonymous>:32:26)
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (<anonymous>:16:9)
at e (jquery.min.js:2)
at t (jquery.min.js:2)
at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:421)
at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:17289)
at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:420)
at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:188)
at push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask (zone.js:496)
at ZoneTask.invoke (zone.js:485)
```

and the result also not working as well. I don't know what make this error happens even my code is the same as that sample in the live site. and I also added scripts that they need as well.

```
<script src="assets/js/threejs/three.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/threejs/Projector.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/threejs/CanvasRenderer.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/threejs/stats.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

https://threejs.live/is not the official website of the project. The official examples are hosted here: https://threejs.org/examples/

`CanvasRenderer` has been removed with `R98` over a year ago. So you can't use this type of renderer and `SpriteCanvasMaterial` with the latest `three.js` version anymore.

The solution is the usage of `WebGLRenderer`. The linked example is also available as a WebGL demo: https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_points_waves

`three.js R111`